# c++ vector of pointers to vector of pointers ordering

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, stdvector

I have two classes, each has a vector of pointers to `Data`. What I want to do is to assign pointers in the vector of the class `Sample2` to pointers in the vector of the class `Sample1`.
The problem is that as I assign pointers in the second vector, the order in witch they are stored is that of the first vector. I would like to store them in the order of insertion.

Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; //for sample purposes

// For simplicity, the data is just a string in this example.
using Data = string;
// In the real code there is a class with a certain vector as a member,
// but for this example we can reduce it to just the vector.
using Sample1 = vector<Data*>;
```

**Class Sample2** — the problem is here

```cpp
class Sample2 {
    vector<Data*> autodromos2;

public:
    vector<Data*>& getAutodromos() { return autodromos2; }

    // ** This is the function with the problem. **
    void addAutodromos2(vector<string>& arguments, vector<Data*>& autodromos)
    {
        for (Data* a : autodromos) {
            for (string &s : arguments) {
                if (s == *a) { // The real test is more complex.
                    getAutodromos().push_back(a);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Main function** (generate data and call `addAutodromos2`)

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Create the list of elements to add to a `Sample2`.
    // Note that these are strings, not Data objects (in the real code).
    vector<string> arguments { "fourth", "first", "third" };

    // Create the `Sample1` data with which to work.
    Sample1 s1 {
        new Data("first"), new Data("second"), new Data("third"), 
        new Data("fourth"), new Data("fifth") 
    };

    // Create the `Sample2` data from the list and `s1`.
    Sample2 s2;
    s2.addAutodromos2(arguments, s1);

    // Diagnostic:
    for (Data* a : s2.getAutodromos()) {
        cout << *a << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```cpp
first 
third 
fourth
```

when it should be

```cpp
fourth 
first 
third
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the sequence problem with loops in `addAutodromos2()` you need to change function with below code:

```
    for (string s : arguments) 
    {
        for (Data* a : autodromos) 
        {            
            if (s == *a) { // The real test is more complex.
                getAutodromos().push_back(a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Switch the for-loops. output is `fourth first third`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a school of thought that says if you have nested loops inside a function, you probably are not thinking abstractly enough. While that might be an overstatement at times, it does have value in this situation. Let's look at the inner loop.

```
            for (string s : arguments) {
                if (s == *a) {
                    getAutodromos().push_back(a);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This loop searches for `*a` in `arguments` and if found does something. The search is a concept that could be abstracted away into its own function, let's call it `found`, a function that returns a `bool`.

```
    // Preliminary revision
    void addAutodromos2(vector<string>& arguments, vector<Data*>& autodromos)
    {
        for (Data* a : autodromos) {
            if ( found(arguments, *a) ) {
                getAutodromos().push_back(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

With only one loop to look at, it should be clearer what the problem is. Elements are added to `getAutodromos()` in the order they appear in `autodromos`. To use the order within `arguments`, you need to loop through it. (I'll change the name of the helper function to `find_by_name` and have it return either an iterator to the found element or the end iterator. A boolean return value is no longer adequate.)

```
    // Final revision
    void addAutodromos2(vector<string>& arguments, vector<Data*>& autodromos)
    {
        for (string s : arguments) {
            auto result = find_by_name(autodromos, s);
            if ( result != autodromos.end() ) {
                getAutodromos().push_back(*result);
            }
        }
    }
```

A missing piece here is the `find_by_name` function. The good news is that this task is so common, [that functionality is part of the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), in the header `<algorithm>`. The bad news is that there is a bit of typing to use the library function, as the arguments are more complex (for greater flexibility). You may want to define a wrapper to specialize it to your case.

```
// Returns an iterator to the element with the indicated name, or
// autodromos.end() if not found.
static auto find_by_name(const vector<Data*> & autodromos, const string & name)
{
    return std::find_if(autodromos.begin(), autodromos.end(), [&name](Data *a){
        return name == *a; // or name == a->get_name(), when Data is more complex
    });
}
```

Note that if the real test was as simple as comparing `name == *a`, then `std::find` could be used instead of `std::find_if`, and there would be no need to use a lambda.
Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>` earlier in the file.